# Netlify is not renderign what is inside the div with the "root" id in react

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I upload a react app to Netlify, it uploads fine, but when I visit the site, it´s all blank, the index.html is working fine, but there is nothing inside the div with the "root" id

Here are the buils settings [image]

here are the enviorment settings [image]

here is the package json [image]

and i also include the redirects file in the public folder

Can you help me to make the react app works

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named _redirects to the **public** folder of App with the following content:

```
/* /index.html 200
```

Sometimes work!

Comment: I already include it, and it does not work neither